# Database design & referential integrity

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I am designing a website UI (Signup, signin, edit profile, edit address, etc..)

I have created the following tables. My question is, are there any redundant columns or tables? Also, which columns will be primary key and which will be foreign keys considering the fact that a user may add/edit another address?

I am using three dropdown lists for `CountryCode` (for mobile no.) - populated from `CountryCode` of `ACountry`, `Country` (for address) - populated from `Country Name` from `ACountry` and `State` (for address) - populated from `StateName` from `Astate`. Out of these, the country code dropdown comes on the signup page. The other 2 are on the address book page that is displayed after the user is logged in. The `AUser` & `AUserAddress` tables will store the data.

I have no idea how I am going to join these tables. Have I included sufficient/more/less columns? What changes should I make.

UPDATE1:
I have updated the database to the following tables/columns. Now how do I establish a relationship between Countrycode & Countrycode (marked)... Or should I drop CountryCode from AUser. If I keep it both the tables I'll be storing data in 2 places. I dont want to do that... The problem is the format of the Countrycode. It takes the name AND the dialing code (e.g. India(+91)). If I drop that column from AUser, how will I store the mobile nos. then? 
May be I'll have to break the Country code string and remove the dialing code part and store it with the mobile no. in the Mobile column. That sounds too complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only relationship you haven't got right is between `AUser` and `ACountry`. Currently, you have `CountryCode` on `AUser`. That should be `CountryID` instead, as that's the primary key of `ACountry`.

Also, shouldn't `AUserAddress` have `StateID` and not `State`? If that's the case, there's no need to have both `StateID` and `CountryID` on that table, you can determine the Country of a user by looking at the corresponding `State` referenced in the `StateID` column.

Comment: But then how(where) do I store the country code for the mobile number.
The country code field has values like this: India(+91)

Comment: @AdityaNawandar You'd have to link the `CountryID` to the `AUser`, then you can store the `TelephoneCode` on the `Country` in a new column (I presumed that's what `CountryCode` was)

Comment: I am getting a little confused here. Should I change the CountryCode column in AUser to Country_ID or..........??

Comment: @AdityaNawandar Yeah change it to `CountryID`. That makes things referentially integral

Comment: Sorry but I am gonna have to ask this again then... where do I store the country codes for the mobile no. ?  I gave an e.g. of the country codes that I have - India(+91)...

Comment: @AdityaNawandar No problems, have another field in the `Country` table called `DiallingCode`.

Comment: Thanks... I have got some new doubts that I'll need to get cleared first. This helped though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26626/discussion-between-aditya-nawandar-and-mattytommo)